# Google Script: Extract data from two columns and dynamically create div classes

Tags: jquery, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two columns. You can find the sample [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g81Brt3gqvQ3ECzS2oDMbRVHrgiE7yB_K3cYWP1XsuM/edit?usp=sharing).

I am trying to write a script in Google Scripts that will allow me to extract all the values from column 1 and put it into a specific `button` tag and the values from column 2 in a separate class with a `p` tag.

This is the code I have if someone were to handwrite the content within Google Scripts:

```
<button class="accordion">Here is a question</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Here is an answer</p>
</div> 

<button class="accordion">Here is another question</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Here is another answer</p>
</div> 

<button class="accordion">Here is a final question</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Here is a final answer</p>
</div>
```

I want to create a script that will dynamically create this table-like structure in Google Scripts with JQuery.

Currently, this is what I have with GS:

In my Code.gs file, I have this:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate()
}
```

In my Utils.gs file, I have this:

```
function test() {
  var n = "seperatertext";
  var this_file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var this_sheet = this_file.getSheets()[0];
  this_file.setActiveSheet(this_sheet); 
  /* var that needs to change from script to script */
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1F1bH0dzR5-UglxWtByS3ojePVEG2aW7qISOgNQ43fz8'); /* <<<< CHANGE THE ID >>>> */
  /* Give an indication to the use that the script is working*/
  var faqlist = this_file.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var faqnum = faqlist.filter(String).length;
  var n = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= faqnum; i++) {
   first = "A".concat(i);
   second = "B".concat(i);
   n.push(this_file.getRange(first).getValue(),"seperatertext", this_file.getRange(second).getValue(),"seperatertext");
  }
  return n;
}
```

This function is copied from another sheet that correctly extracts the data but in a different HTML structure so I'm not sure why it's not working with this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need two components for this:

1. Sever-side `.gs` scripts to interact with the data.
2. Client-side HTML and jQuery to request and display the data.

Your first attempt is close. You need to use the `.ready()` function to send a request to the script and then process the returned array with some kind of jQuery constructor.

This (simplified) script will dynamically create divs based on the data in the spreadsheet when the app loads.

**Utils.gs**

```js
function getData() {
  // Using getActiveSpreadsheet() only works with bound scripts.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  // I don't like getSheets() because indicies change if sheets are reordered. Consider using getSheetByName() instead.
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // This returns a 2D array of data you can manipulate
  var faqList = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();

  // Send the array to the client
  return faqList
}
```

**Code.gs**

```js
// This serves templated HTML, meaning you can have variables defined.
// index.html can include scripts for working with data.
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <!-- load jQuery here -->
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- load an empty container for the spreadsheet data -->
  <div id="container"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Call the Google function right away
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildDivs).getData()
  })

  function buildDivs(data) {
    // Loop the data to build the divs
    var container = $("#container");
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      var el = "<button class='accordion'>" + data[i][0] + "</button><div class='panel'><p>" + data[i][1] + "</p></div>"

      container.appendChild(el);
    }
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```